# UltraWingrid - Thousand separator on a string column

Tags: string, format, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a string column in my ultrawingrid, which contains integer data. I need to use thousand separator on that column. But, when I used format property, I realized it does not work on a string column.

Does someone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can someone please respond to it?

Comment: Use Infragistics Tag. You will get more attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to associate a IDataFilter derived class to the Editor.DataFilter property of your column.
Suppose for example you have a bound column named 'NumberCode' of type string, put this code in the InitializeLayout event of your grid

```
UltraGridColum cl = e.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["NumberCode"];
cl.Editor.DataFilter = new ThousandSeparator();
```

and then create a simple class that implements the interface IDataFilter like this:

```
public class ThousandFormatter : IEditorDataFilter
{
    public ThousandFormatter()
    { }

    public object Convert(EditorDataFilterConvertArgs conversionArgs)
    {
        if (conversionArgs.Direction == ConversionDirection.OwnerToEditor)
        {
            UltraGridCell cell = conversionArgs.Context as UltraGridCell;
            if (cell != null && cell.Column.Key == "NumberCode")
            {
                conversionArgs.Handled = true;
                decimal dValue = System.Convert.ToDecimal(conversionArgs.Value);
                return dValue.ToString("#,##0");
            }
        }
        return conversionArgs.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where this Convert function to be called at??

Comment: It's the UltraWinGrid control that calls convert when it needs to display your cell value. Keep in mind that this function will be called also for ConversionDirection.EditorToOwner. Set a breakpoint on the first if and then run your program, it will be hit when you exit form the InitializeLayout event.

Comment: Convert function is not being called.

Comment: That's strange. There is nothing you should do apart to set the property DataFilter on the desidered column to a new instance of ThousandFormatter. Usually this is done in the InitializeLayout Event for which you need to create the appropriate plumbing (method code and event handler association). Tested here and works fine.

Comment: My mistake, the handler was missing in my Convert function. That works now. But the issue with the implemented functionality is when I click on a cell to edit it, it still shows the comma separator. My requirement is NOT to show the comma separator when the cell is in edit mode.

Comment: Please check the ConversionDirection enum. You will find here that there are other directions in which the Convert method will be called. You should add an if test for conversonArgs.Direction == ConversionDirection.EditorToDisplay and ConversionDirection.DisplayToEditor. Place the appropriate code in this test to convert the before editing starts or after editing ends.

Comment: Hi Steve,

Can you tell me if there will be a performance impact if using this for bulk data ~1,000,000 rows

Comment: I really don't know. I doubt that you could really load so many rows and in any case you user will be absolutely incapable of making any sense from this big resultset. Better focus on smaller set of data with some kind of query before trying to load the grid.